# VBA : Runtime Error 9 - Seems it can't find Public Function in the same UserForm code module

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Here is the code for the UserForm that I'm building, everything run smoothly with a test Array.

I'm looking for partial match with the **public function GetMatchingArt**, which is fine on his own, to add an `OptionButton` for each match.

But when I try to **call this function** in the `UserForm_Initialize` it systematicly give me the **Runtime error 9** (Subscript out of range).

Meaning that it can't find the function, altough it is **Public** and even if they are **in the same module** (Code module of the UF).

There is the `UserForm_Initialize` and I can't seem to find a way to call my function...

```
Private Opt As MSForms.OptionButton
Private Prod()
Private Stock()


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim MaxWidth As Long, _
    TotalHeight As Long, _
    A()
MaxWidth = 0

'Add_Options (Split("test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7", ","))

'Call GetMatchingArt
'A = GetMatchingArt()
'Add_Options A
'Add_Options GetMatchingArt
Add_Options GetMatchingArt()





For i = 0 To UF_Prod.Controls.Count - 1
    If UF_Prod.Controls(i).Width > MaxWidth Then MaxWidth = UF_Prod.Controls(i).Width
    TotalHeight = TotalHeight + UF_Prod.Controls(i).Height * 11 / 10
Next i

Me.Height = TotalHeight
Me.Width = MaxWidth * 12 / 10

If Me.CommandButton1.Width >= MaxWidth Then Me.CommandButton1.Width = 6 * MaxWidth / 10

Me.CommandButton1.Top = Me.Height - Me.CommandButton1.Height * 7 / 4
Me.CommandButton1.Left = (Me.Width - Me.CommandButton1.Width) / 2

MsgBox "UF ready", vbinfo, "Loaded UF"
End Sub
```

Here is the function :

```
Public Function GetMatchingArt() As Variant
LoadInfo
Dim cVal As String, _
    A() 

cVal = ActiveCell.Value2

For i = LBound(Prod, 1) To UBound(Prod, 1)
    If InStr(1, Prod(i, 1), cVal) Then
        A(UBound(A)) = Prod(i, 1)
        ReDim Preserve A(UBound(A) + 1)
    Else
        'No match
    End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve A(UBound(A) - 1)

GetMatchingArt = A
End Function
```

And the rest of the code I use (which didn't have problems) :

```
Public Sub LoadInfo()
    Prod = Sheets("Products").UsedRange.Value2
    Stock = Sheets("Stock").UsedRange.Value2
End Sub


Sub Add_Options(ByVal Arr As Variant)

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Set Opt = UF_Prod.Controls.Add("Forms.optionButton.1", "Opt" & i, True)
    With Opt
        .Caption = Arr(i)
        .Top = Opt.Height * Int((i + 1) / 2)
        .Left = 10 + (Int((i + 1) / 2) * 2 - i) * UF_Prod.Width / 2
    End With
    Set Opt = Nothing
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: From what I can see having a quick look over your code. You are trying to add a new options button in the initalize event. As far as I know, you cannot do this as the code gets called before anything has been truely initalized. Try putting the code in activate rather than initialise

Comment: @Sam : Awesome! :)
That work perfectly now! I haven't done an UF in a long time, I totally forgot that! Make an answer so I can accept it and close this! ;)

Comment: No problem. I will make an answer now. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see having a quick look over your code. You are trying to add a new options button in the initalize event. As far as I know, you cannot do this as the code gets called before anything has been truely initalized. Try putting the code in activate rather than initialise

EDIT. Turns out you can insert buttons in initalize. However this code did not and worked on the activate event. So something in the code was trying to use something that had not been initialised.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not true. You can most certainly add controls in the `Initialize` event - I do it all the time.

Comment: Then in this case, since it worked. Something else must not of loaded yet to be able to run the code. So it would be better to do it once the form has been fully initialized and in the activate event

Comment: Perhaps, but you really ought to edit your answer I think since it's incorrect as it stands. ;)